# В чем разница между созданием RestTempate с помощью конструктора и со связыванием с помощью аннотации @Autowired?

Tags: java, spring, rest, mocking, юнит-тесты

Всем привет!

Тестирую сервис на рест запросы, и необходимо протестировать rest call что они по заданому uri корректно десериализируют объект.
Дело в том, когда я объект RestTemplate подвешиваю аннотацией @Autowired, то тесты проходят, а когда создаю с помощью конструктора в самом методе, то тесты падают.

**Вот пример теста:**

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {RestTemplate.class, SimpleRestService.class})
public class SimpleRestServiceFunctionalTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {
@Autowired
private SimpleRestService simpleRestService;

@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

private MockRestServiceServer mockServer;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
}

@Test
public void testGetMessage() {
    mockServer.expect(requestTo("https://google.com")).andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
            .andRespond(withSuccess("resultSuccess", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));

    String result = simpleRestService.getMessage();
    System.out.println("result: "+result);

    mockServer.verify();
    assertThat(result, allOf(containsString("SUCCESS"), containsString("resultSuccess")));
}

@Test
public void testGetMessage_500() {
    mockServer.expect(requestTo("https://google.com")).andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
            .andRespond(withServerError());

    String result = simpleRestService.getMessage();
    System.out.println("result: "+result);

    mockServer.verify();
    assertThat(result, allOf(containsString("FAILED"), containsString("500")));
}

@Test
public void testGetMessage_404() {
    mockServer.expect(requestTo("https://google.com")).andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
            .andRespond(withStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));

    String result = simpleRestService.getMessage();
    System.out.println("result: "+result);

    mockServer.verify();
    assertThat(result, allOf(containsString("FAILED"), containsString("404")));
}
}
```

**Пример сервиса:**(т.е. если здесь будет юзать resttemplate с помощью @Autowired, то все хорошо. а если буду создавать явно в методе resttemplate, то тесты упадут)

```
@Service
public class SimpleRestService {

//    @Autowired
//    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

public String getMessage() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String result;
    try {
        String httpResult = restTemplate.getForObject("https://google.com", String.class);
        result = "Message SUCCESS result: " + httpResult;
    } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
        result = "Get FAILED with HttpStatusCode: " + e.getStatusCode() + "|" + e.getStatusText();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        result = "Get FAILED\n" + ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(e);
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

**Вопрос:** В чем разница в этих двух подходах? **и второй вопрос:** как протестировать этот сервис на валидное возвращения сообщения, если создавать RestTemplate явно в методе?

Comment: Потому что это Spring и в нем есть условия по работе с контекстом, не буду вдаваться в подробности(для этого есть много литературы)
там где есть внедрение  бина - там не должно быть слова new

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что @Autowired -- автоматически настраивает бобы. А с вашим подходом, вы просто создаете новую ссылку, когда этот боб может иметь какие либо другие бобы в конструкторе.

Вы можете протестировать этот боб явно в методе, если узнаете все его зависимости других бобов и будете добавлять их в конструктор. Но чем вас неустраивает @Autowired?

Comment: на счет этого понятно. не понятно, почему, когда я ставлю аннотацию на resttemplate тесты не падают, а когда явно создаю в методах, то вываливается - result: Message SUCCESS result: <!doctype html><html itemscope="".... Вот интересно почему оно так.

Comment: Message SUCCESS result -- успешно ведь?

Comment: нет, это сообщение, которое идет первым в методе сервиса SimpleRestService getMessage()